# How does Kahoot know if content is fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

How does Kahoot know if content is fullscreen?

I was playing Kahoot on a Chromebook. On many chromebooks, there is func button that "hides" the tab bar, in short, fullscreen the webpage and hide the tab changer, URL bar, and bookmarks bar to make the webpage bigger. It is not considered fullscreen, the "press [esc] to exit fullscreen" does not appear, and when I direct my mouse up the X does not appear (to exit fullscreen), but instead everything that was hidden appears again, but it is over the web content, so the webpage does not resize, but part of it is covered by the tabs bar. When I move my mouse downwards, the bar goes away again.

However, I noticed that if I was in the chrome fullscreen mode (described above), the fullscreen option on Kahoot was blanked out, as such:

[image: img1]

That means that it could detect it.

[image: imgb]

If I was not in the chrome fullscreen mode, it would show up black, and I would be able to enter fullscreen using the button (by kahoot making the document of the page fullscreenelement)

I then did a check for the fullscreen element while in the chrome fullscreen mode:

[image: 3333]

Therefore, there is no fullscreen element. So,
How can kahoot  detect if I am in the Chromebook fullscreen mode, if there is no fullscreenelement?

Comment: please someone answer